# Hiding and Showing a Component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

App.vue

```
<HeaderPart></HeaderPart>
<router-view />
<PlayerBar v-if="audio"></PlayerBar>
```

I want to Hide/Show this PlayerBar using functions, In main.js i have created all the function to alter the value of audio.

```
Vue.mixin({
  data: function() {
    return {
      baseURL: "https://sampleurl",
      authToken: "sampleauth",
      watch: false,
      audio: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    playaudio(item) {
      window.Amplitude.playNow(item);
    },
    playvideo() {
      this.audio = false;
      this.watch = true;
      console.log(this.audio);
    },
    stopvideo() {
      this.watch = false;
      this.audio = true;
      console.log(this.audio);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      cur_user: "user"
    })
  }
});
```

So Whenever playvideo, the Playerbar will be hidden, and when he close video, playerbar will be shown. in Console.log, Values are coming fine, Audio is changing to true/false but playerbar not getting hidden on frontend

Comment: try <PlayerBar v-if="!watch"></PlayerBar>

Answer (score 0):

try v-show instead of v-if 
`<PlayerBar v-show="audio"></PlayerBar>`

Comment: No Effect, already tried with v-show and v-if both

Answer (score 0):

It might the naming conflict with the Vue component "watch" option ([Vue watch option](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch))

Comment: There is no conflict, as Upon Watch True, Video popup is showing, but audio playerbar not getting hide, also I have tried changing Watch Variable to watchvideo, still no luck

Comment: also consider NOT using global mixins (Vue.mixin) - it adds your func-ty to ALL Vue instances.